# SO chat bug ping many

Tags: feature-request, bug, chat

If you put a @string in a chat it pings everyone with that string in their name.  Why hasn't this bug been corrected, so people don't exploit/abuse it?

Comment: that's because of [Tim](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/132562/165773)

Comment: MSE dupe: [Stack Exchange chat name mention inbox confusion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66290)

Comment: And a more recent MSE post with a test of the better match heuristics: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/166915/158100

Comment: And if people abuse it, they'll rapidly find themselves unable to use chat as moderators happily will ban users for that kind of behaviour.